# how to pass a jquery variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, variables

hi there im trying to pass my jquery variable onto php

j query bit

```
 <script> $(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" );
});

$("#resizable").resizable({ maxWidth: 500,  minWidth: 250 ,handles:'e', grid: [1, 1] } );
 var txt =$("#resizable").width() * 2;  $("#test").text('Template Width: ' + txt + 'px');
 $("#resizable").resize(function() {
     txt = $("#resizable").width() * 2;
      $("#test").text('Template Width:' + txt + 'px');
```

what i want to do is call my txt variable into php for example

```
<?php $templatewidth = (myjquery variable txt) ;?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to make an XHR to the server to send that variable to PHP.

Look at the j[Query AJAX methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/).

Answer (score 2):

1. PHP runs on the server, generates some output.
2. The server delivers that output to the browser
3. The browser runs any client side JavaScript in the page

It is **too late** to send data back to the instance of the PHP program that generated the page.

You can send new data by making an HTTP request (e.g. via XMLHttpRequest), get a response in JS and then handle that new data in JS.