# Parse javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

This is my first post and every opinion/help will be much appreciated by me.

I am new to php and javascript.
So lets start...

What i want to do is parse a variable to an external php form every time a person clicks on text.
For example lets assume that i have the following string echoed `$test = "what a beautiful day";`
I want when a person clicks on "what" the `"phpquery?test=what"` to be triggered.
From what i have read javascript can help with that because of the client side scripting logic
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Do you want the user to be redirected to phpquery or just for that page to run?

Comment: See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175724/how-to-pass-a-jquery-variable-to-php) also asked very recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would parse the sentence in such a way that each word is encapsulated in a  tag. For example:

```
<span class="clickable">What</span> <span class="clickable">a</span> <span class="clickable">wonderful</span> <span class="clickable">day</span>
```

than you can bind a click function to each of these spans like so using JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("span.clickable").bind("click", function() {
          var wordClicked = $(this).html();
          $.get("phpquery?word=" + wordClicked );
    }); 
});
```

and do as SalmanPK suggested and use the $.get to send the word click to PHP :)

HTH

Comment: Better to do the span encapsulation on client side. look at my solution. This way you can focus on outputting the text you want, and dont add encapsulation logic to the server side. And in addition, the only reason why we are encapsulating is to make the parts of the text clickable. so it's very tied to the js functionality anyways.

Comment: Yeah nice solution ... tho I wouldn't go through that hassle if it's not too expensive for him to do it server side :)

Comment: Isn't the hassle equally large on server-side if not larger? In addition the http payload get's larger.. serverside processing time is greater. i fail too see any pro's of doing it on serverside contra clientside.

Comment: agreed it's probably better his way

Comment: thank you ElGabbu and SalmanPK you helped me very much!!!!!! if i come up with a new question i will ask again. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is usually handed via [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/), usually abstracted via [a library that irons out the differences between browsers](http://microjs.com/#ajax) (bigger libraries that do lots of other stuff include [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to do that using AJAX.

Have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com), its very easy to learn for newbies.

You can accomplish this with jQuery using this simple piece of code:-

```
$('a').click(function(){  // You can use a css selector to select your anchor tag
    $.get("phpquery?test=what");
});
```

Comment: After binding it to the onclick of the sentence and assigning a callback function

Comment: @SalmanPK - He should learn javascript before learning that jQuery is not a programming language.

Comment: Christian Sciberras, Wrong place to argue about that sir, you know he can't.

Comment: thank you ElGabbu and SalmanPK you helped me very much!!!!!! if i come up with a new question i will ask again. thank you

Comment: your very welcome. I would appreciate a vote up for the answer or maybe mark as answer :)

Comment: i would vote up for both of you but i cant due to reputation restriction so i can only mark one answer...

Comment: i did something like that  instead
<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$pieces = explode(" ", $row['perigrafi']);       
$count=sizeof($pieces);
for($counter=0;$counter<$count;$counter++){
echo "<dd class=\"greek\"><dfn id=\"1\"></dfn>$pieces[$counter]</dd><a href=\"test.php?url=$url\" class=\"x87\">";
}
echo "<br />";
mysql_data_seek($result,0);
?>
but the first result doesnt return as hyperlink...

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse in most cases XMLHttpRequest would be suitable, but maybe you prefer the simple solution:

```
window.location.search = "?test=what";
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of how you could achieve the click handling with jQuery, and also how you can do an ajax call (commented out after alert)

http://jsfiddle.net/UgXAH/1/

HTML:

```
<p class="interactive">this is some text</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$().ready(function(){
    var textArray = $('.interactive').text().split(' ')
    $('.interactive').empty()
    $(textArray).each(function(){
        var textItem = $('<span>'+this+' </span>')
        textItem.click(function(){
            var text = $(this).text()
            alert('fire off ajax request with text='+text)            
            /*$.ajax({
                url:'some-url.php',
                data:{
                    text:text
                }      
            })*/
        })
        $('.interactive').append(textItem)
    })
})
```

Comment: hello netbrain. can you please tell me how to make go to the url?